# How does Riesz representation theorem give us the left invariance of the Radon measure from a left invariant positive linear functional on $C_c(G)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

I am trying to understand the end of the (canonical) proof of the existence of Haar measure on a locally compact group by Riesz representation theorem.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $C_c(G)$ denote the set of all compactly supported function on $G$. Suppose $I$ is a **left-invariant** positive linear functional on $C_c(G)$ (Here, by left-invariant we mean $I(L_x f)=I(f)$ for any $x\in G$, where $L_x f(y)=f(xy)$ ).

By Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique Radon measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that

$$I(f)=\int_Gfd\mu, \forall f\in C_c(G).$$

From here I can use the Urysohn's lemma, monotone convergence theorem, etc. to conclude that $$\mu(xU)=\mu(U)$$

for any $x\in G$ and **open** subsets $U$ of $G$. But I wonder how to prove that

$$\mu(xE)=\mu(E)$$

for any $x\in G$ and **Borel** subset $E$ of $G$ (so that $\mu$ is a left invariant Haar measure on $G$).

---

Note that [the latter doesn't follow from the former immediately](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874128/if-two-borel-measures-coincide-on-all-open-sets-are-they-equal?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *uniqueness* part of the theorem.  For each $x\in G$, the measure $\mu_x(E)=\mu(xE)$ satisfies $$\int f d\mu_x=\int L_{x^{-1}}f d\mu=I(L_{x^{-1}}f)=I(f)$$ for all $f\in C_c(G)$.  By the uniqueness of $\mu$, this implies $\mu=\mu_x$.

Or more directly, the fact that $\mu$ (and hence also $\mu_x$) is a *Radon* measure implies that it is uniquely determined by its values on open sets, by outer regularity.

Comment: Thanks! But for your second paragraph, how to see that $\mu_x$ a Radon measure from $\mu$ being Radon? The outer regularity of $\mu_x$ is not obvious to me since at this point we don't know whether $\mu$ is left invariant yet...

Comment: Multiplication by $x$ is a homeomorphism, so it sends Radon measures to Radon measures.