# Two measures that agree on set of fixed length intervals in $R$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$,$\nu$ be two $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. 
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be Borel $\sigma$ algebra generated by open sets in 
$\mathbb{R}$.

Prove or disprove: $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\ \ \mu([t,t+1])=\nu([t,t+1])\implies\forall A\in\mathcal{B}\ \ \mu(A)=\nu(A)$$

My attempt:

I tried to prove: $$\forall t,s\in\mathbb{R}\quad\mu([t,t+1]\cap[s,s+1])=\nu([t,t+1]\cap[s,s+1])
$$
Then using the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, I'll be able to prove $\sigma(\mathcal{I})\subseteq D$

where $\mathcal{I}:=\{I|\exists t,r\in\mathbb{R},\,0\leq r\leq1\ \  s.t\ \  I=[t,t+r]\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$

$$D:=\{A\in\mathcal{B}|\forall Bounded\ \ closed\ \ interval\ \ I\subset\mathbb{R}\ \ \mu(I)=\nu(I)\}$$

Very similar to what was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/931970).

I couldn't prove that, so I tried to find a counter example.
I notice that by changing the assumption to:

$$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\ \ \mu([t,t+1))=\nu([t,t+1))\implies\forall A\in\mathcal{B}\ \ \mu(A)=\nu(A)
$$
I could come up with a counter example by defining $\mu$ to be the 
standard Lebesgue measure, and $\nu$ to be a measure that counts 
the number of integers, i.e

$\forall A\in\mathcal{B}\ \ \nu(A)=|\mathbb{N}\cap A|$.

I couldn't modify the counter example to fit to the original assumption, 
and because it is not valid for the next assumption:
$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\ \ \mu((t,t+1))=\nu((t,t+1))\implies\forall A\in\mathcal{B}\ \ \mu(A)=\nu(A)
$$
I started thinking it was “too” artificial.

How should I precede?

BTW: It was homework for “introduction to real analysis” class, it's 
not anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive continuous periodic functions with period $1$ such that $\int_0^{1}f(x) dx=\int_0^{1}g(x) dx$. Let $\mu (E)=\int_E f(x)dx$ and $\nu (E)=\int_E g(x)dx$. Then $\mu [t,t+1]=\int_t^{t+1} f(x)dx=\int_0^{1}f(x) dx=\int_0^{1}g(x) dx=\nu [t,t+1]$. But $\mu =\nu$ is true only when $f=g$. Can you find an example where $f \neq g$?